# Is it possible to move the filtering section to context menu in AG-Grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'd like to add this filtering option when you click the three bars beside the headerName, into the context menu.

[image: Picture of filtering button]

Alternatively, is it possible to configure an additional context menu item I can add named "Hide Column" which'll toggle "hide"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`customColumns` property can be used in the grid options to define a function to generate the context menu items and add the filtering options in it.

```
var gridOptions = {
    //grid options
    customColumns: function(params) {
        var menuItems = [];
        menuItems.push({
            name: 'Filter...',
            action: function() {
                // filter options
            }
        });
        return menuItems;
    }
}
```

and for 2nd part `hide` property can be used in the grid options to hide a column dynamically.

```
customColumns: function(params) {
        var menuItems = [];
        menuItems.push({
            name: 'Hide Column',
            action: function() {
                params.columnApi.setColumnVisible(params.column.colId, false);
            }
        });
        return menuItems;
    }
```

refer to this for more: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-context-menu/

Comment: Thank you! So if I right click any row within the grid, the first block of code can help display all of the checkboxes as shown in the picture inside that context menu and update column visibility?